# Facebook images not working in dialogflow chatbot integration

Tags: json, facebook, messenger, dialogflow-es

i'm trying to make work the Dialogflow (online platform) chatbot in Facebook but seems it doesn't recognizing the images. Here is my code:

```
{
"facebook": {
"attachment": {
  "type": "template",
  "payload": {
    "template_type": "generic",
    "elements": [
      {
        "title": "Welcome to Peter's Hats",
        "image_url": "https://alfi.de/media/logo/stores/1/alfi-Logo-small.jpg",
        "subtitle": "We've got the right hat for everyone.",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "web_url",
            "url": "https://google.com",
            "title": "View Website"
          },
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "title": "Start Chatting"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
  }
}
```

the fact is that works with this code:

```
{
 "facebook": {
"attachment": {
  "type": "image",
  "payload": {
    "url": "https://alfi.de/media/logo/stores/1/alfi-Logo-small.jpg"
  }
}
  }
}
```

then, I tryed several combinations, but seems the image works better alone. I also tryed different templates, but seems not to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Dialogflow's API are you using?

Comment: I'm using the integrate tool, no versions, just the online plattform.